# How does addStylesSet interact with the contents css?

Tags: ckeditor

I have redirected the contents.css file for my CKEditor 3.6 to my site's stylesheet:

```
 CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/css/style.css';
```

Now I'd like to add some styles from that stylesheet into the dropdown box for users to select when editing content.  The previous developer created this:

```
CKEDITOR.addStylesSet( 'cms_styles',
[
    {
        name : 'Page Header',
        element : 'h2'
    },

    {
        name : 'Page Text',
        element : 'p'
    },
```

It appears to work, but makes very little sense to me.  Where do these get their style from given that a class name cannot have spaces?  Why is an element being specified if we're just adding styles to the dropdown?  Google turned up no good results for addStylesSet, and the developer guide I found (http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles) really wasn't very specific.

I do not want to display all available classes; just a few that we define.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` property on the style objects is only used for display purposes, it does not make it into the content in any way. What the previous developer created works because those styles are just specifying the element, and the css likely has styling defined using those element specifiers.

The `element` property is being set so that CKEditor knows how to apply that style to the content. If you have a style with the `element` property having a value of `p` then that style will become a block style and will apply to the currently active `p` block in the content. If the `element` property has a value of `span` then the style would be applied to the selected text only (it would be surrounded with a `span` element if one didn't already exist).

To get styles in the dropdown to represent classes in your external css you need to add the style objects to the styles set and have it set the `class` attribute of the element the style is being applied to. By setting properties on the `attributes` property of the style object you can have CKEditor add or modify attributes on the element that it is applying the style to. For our purposes we want to set the `class` property of the `attributes` property in order to have the class defined in your css applied.

CSS:

```
p.myBlockStyle {
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

CKEditor stylesSet array:

```
[
    {
        name: "My Block Style", 
        element: "p", 
        attributes: { 
            "class": "myBlockStyle" 
        }
    }
]
```

Note that the `class` property has it's name quoted because `class` is a reserved keyword.